# XML namespace change in payload C#

Tags: c#, xml, soap, xml-namespaces, webservice-client

I am calling web service method that takes request object with few parameter. Xml that i am sending is :

```html
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none"></Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <findRequest xmlns="http://servicesweow2.com">
      <parameter>
        <name>IsClosed</name>
        <value>true</value>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <name>IsDistinct</name>
        <value>false</value>
      </parameter>
    </findRequest>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

but in the example xml looks like :

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ser="http://servicesweow2.com">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<ser:findRequest>
<ser:parameter>
<ser:name>IsClosed</ser:name>
<ser:value>true</ser:value>
</ser:parameter>
<ser:parameter>
<ser:name>IsDistinct</ser:name>
<ser:value>false</ser:value>
</ser:parameter>

</ser:findRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

All i am doing in code is calling method and passing new object. Is there way to change XML namespace **< s:** to **< soapenv:**  and add **< ser:** before parameters ?
Code used:

```
        MyService src = new MyService();
        findRequest req = new findRequest();
        var response = src.findTasks(req);
```

Comment: Are you manually generating the Soap calls to the Service or did you add it as a service reference and let visual studio generate the client proxy for you?  If you added it as a service reference inside that Proxy thats generated should be a class which you would populate to pass to the soap function and it should have the correct namespaces.

Comment: As XML documents these two are 100% equivalent (except that the Action header element is missing from the latter), so why do you need to change the namespace prefixes?

Comment: @Bearcat9425 Yes i did add it as service refrence and visual studio did created all files.

Comment: @Ben Jackson well tho be honest i am not sure how important is namespace in xml. What would happen if other party recived xml that contains <:s tag instead of <ser: tag ? I think they would be able to parse it for some reason i think different tags is needed.

Comment: Are you receiving errors? or just noticed that there is a difference in your serialized XML on your side vs what the service says its expecting?

Comment: @Bearcat9425 well not at all only that i am not authorized.. I guess its all right...but i am still wondering how can you change XML namespace..

Comment: The namespace prefixes (e.g. soapenv, ser and s in your data) are just a syntactic shortcut and, assuming the server is properly coded, should be totally irrelevant.  All that should matter is the actual target namespace of each element.  Note that setting the xmlns attribute on an element sets the target namespace directly for that element and all recursive child elements (in the absence of any other controlling attributes), and is thus equivalent to defining a prefix for that namespace and applying it to the element and all child elements - ser in your data.

Comment: I got better insight of xml now, thanks Ben and Bearcat9425 :)